# OpenLayers error "Unsupported GeoJSON type: undefined"

Tags: openlayers, geojson

I'm trying to add Vector Data in my OpenLayers code via GeoJSON.
Unfortunately, I'm getting the following error message:

```
Uncaught Error: Unsupported GeoJSON type: undefined
readGeometry             Karte.f38e3900.js:66345
readFeatureFromObject    Karte.f38e3900.js:66094
readFeaturesFromObject   Karte.f38e3900.js:66142
readFeatures             Karte.f38e3900.js:65759
```

I tried to write a similar GeoJSON as in the [OpenLayers Docs](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/geojson.html?q=geojson).
That's my GeoJSON:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "Gewaesserabschnitte",
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "fid": 1.0, "o2 (in %)": 90.0, "no3 (mg\/l)": 13.0, "ph-wert": 6.0, "nh4 (mg\/l)": 0.04, "no2 (mg\/l)": 0.25, "scale": 8000 }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ 439739.539313841727562, 5536104.445168466307223 ], [ 439732.942652594181709, 5536149.877767100930214 ], [ 439724.574578237719834, 5536164.1462333323434 ], [ 439736.724421020888258, 5536233.464011526666582 ], [ 439741.433762245753314, 5536273.098866205662489 ], [ 439751.716323268250562, 5536302.748997206799686 ], [ 439764.745632711332291, 5536323.863738300278783 ], [ 439775.012061203946359, 5536352.096415889449418 ], [ 439775.250725442543626, 5536373.354598745703697 ], [ 439782.611068246420473, 5536395.950129802338779 ], [ 439794.139357308275066, 5536409.994530701078475 ], [ 439818.759993943909649, 5536450.822065219283104 ], [ 439844.610673918505199, 5536474.627294369973242 ], [ 439985.736823005427141, 5536638.875099274329841 ], [ 440051.487035491736606, 5536672.155328895896673 ], [ 440143.888856283971108, 5536673.958007009699941 ], [ 440372.317061513254885, 5536766.372370785102248 ], [ 440460.46961716003716, 5536769.644936578348279 ], [ 440473.36918710207101, 5536779.422698650509119 ], [ 440494.810719052387867, 5536790.522971729747951 ], [ 440533.461811530054547, 5536815.605149755254388 ], [ 440663.670140638074372, 5536894.946598484180868 ], [ 440769.216827536816709, 5536929.21092477440834 ], [ 440817.843910716357641, 5536957.018729401752353 ], [ 440846.420258281519637, 5536970.875719822943211 ], [ 440895.030938066425733, 5536997.266951928846538 ], [ 440918.016575370915234, 5537019.689084901474416 ], [ 440936.754685975844041, 5537043.575195804238319 ], [ 440941.620893525949214, 5537051.748555677011609 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "fid": 2.0, "o2 (in %)": 90.0, "no3 (mg\/l)": 10.0, "ph-wert": 6.0, "nh4 (mg\/l)": 0.02, "no2 (mg\/l)": 0.3, "scale": 15000 }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ 441384.502329971117433, 5538295.968604033812881 ], [ 441388.248388875974342, 5538304.033650607801974 ], [ 441486.984163766435813, 5538368.13059963285923 ], [ 441613.72860172187211, 5538395.085631323046982 ], [ 441700.340209427522495, 5538389.892494615167379 ], [ 441856.854399741452653, 5538410.862105940468609 ], [ 441888.415076231642161, 5538438.856543784961104 ], [ 441975.378840433200821, 5538466.251040913164616 ], [ 442016.668193216610234, 5538474.305200132541358 ], [ 442053.848760741471779, 5538496.572216054424644 ], [ 442086.629516030778177, 5538506.135648872703314 ], [ 442165.144049378868658, 5538540.708112339489162 ], [ 442211.13713810039917, 5538589.799856159836054 ], [ 442446.169569074874744, 5538646.775909235700965 ], [ 442555.870853041880764, 5538675.351261466741562 ], [ 442661.006258107256144, 5538675.64237295370549 ], [ 442820.968596133461688, 5538621.513294637203217 ], [ 442960.394285945920274, 5538639.862662608735263 ], [ 443026.131175672868267, 5538675.999395100399852 ], [ 443130.176475008483976, 5538707.479852883145213 ], [ 443172.747448852809612, 5538702.778120253235102 ], [ 443261.000582220905926, 5538718.84419612120837 ], [ 443282.488415336818434, 5538735.617697793059051 ], [ 443329.440673049830366, 5538742.204790784046054 ], [ 443349.432817784952931, 5538751.910620216280222 ], [ 443368.124101502704434, 5538772.964098119176924 ], [ 443467.709655237733386, 5538786.080148205161095 ], [ 443503.536020560306497, 5538815.453566912561655 ], [ 443546.270523696497548, 5538826.337035630829632 ], [ 443586.298030430683866, 5538849.999693596735597 ], [ 443681.754028295108583, 5538875.913258275948465 ], [ 443738.976020118454471, 5538896.739871405996382 ], [ 443761.581921286589932, 5538901.815237099304795 ], [ 443814.187996013090014, 5538905.867785341106355 ], [ 443851.575767821806949, 5538915.038655813783407 ], [ 443864.976196811534464, 5538922.86716360040009 ], [ 443879.071991329197772, 5538929.271726904436946 ], [ 443891.558599009003956, 5538934.630651326850057 ], [ 443907.067388471739832, 5538940.312140363268554 ], [ 443914.363977627595887, 5538941.829551027156413 ], [ 443924.865882664569654, 5538944.198861572891474 ], [ 443935.332587927172426, 5538943.203943868167698 ], [ 443948.433051896747202, 5538939.348140553571284 ], [ 443962.572971375659108, 5538933.002304431982338 ], [ 443970.331894341681618, 5538927.785712188109756 ], [ 443977.227094488684088, 5538924.880268247798085 ], [ 443982.372615102911368, 5538924.472317626699805 ], [ 443997.82583151437575, 5538924.842092296108603 ], [ 444007.10331228346331, 5538928.995219810865819 ], [ 444013.695197907858528, 5538931.051386553794146 ], [ 444054.143437356397044, 5538944.264600476250052 ], [ 444096.206383805256337, 5538942.054868498817086 ], [ 444121.928408540145028, 5538939.484544093720615 ], [ 444152.823648773715831, 5538939.162543863989413 ], [ 444165.078898751118686, 5538939.38903502561152 ], [ 444177.530147141078487, 5538941.384362425655127 ], [ 444188.394419938209467, 5538944.458751395344734 ], [ 444197.323970295372419, 5538949.32414941675961 ], [ 444206.255347423488274, 5538954.366622923873365 ], [ 444232.333618677337654, 5538968.970297968015075 ], [ 444258.698727804643568, 5538977.018981007859111 ], [ 444291.430053489981219, 5538982.522438891232014 ], [ 444302.49565111938864, 5538987.897022088058293 ], [ 444330.965492587420158, 5538993.444992841221392 ], [ 444351.395579352974892, 5538994.295335257425904 ], [ 444366.371015909360722, 5538999.983608996495605 ], [ 444432.356563306122553, 5539010.101137483492494 ], [ 444440.531501115066931, 5539010.724719504825771 ], [ 444458.801463377254549, 5539008.764539915136993 ], [ 444474.210355793358758, 5539004.886153449304402 ], [ 444502.187295756302774, 5538997.158921521157026 ], [ 444503.570831720135175, 5538997.400540792383254 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "fid": 3.0, "o2 (in %)": 98.0, "no3 (mg\/l)": 11.0, "ph-wert": 5.5, "nh4 (mg\/l)": 0.1, "no2 (mg\/l)": 0.06, "scale": 2000 }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ 440841.751681211346295, 5538222.189647431485355 ], [ 440841.759497715334874, 5538222.898008081130683 ], [ 440878.743717488949187, 5538226.740707055665553 ], [ 440907.81272040377371, 5538221.461094811558723 ], [ 441019.780499434447847, 5538196.140885054133832 ], [ 441047.343435671937186, 5538183.085618677549064 ], [ 441063.502121792698745, 5538166.613556492142379 ], [ 441096.919274230254814, 5538169.080115532502532 ], [ 441111.235016541846562, 5538178.841180927120149 ], [ 441162.63598513440229, 5538201.655675104819238 ], [ 441237.50079256342724, 5538226.338652867823839 ], [ 441259.066902287711855, 5538249.480941305868328 ], [ 441304.644334121025167, 5538259.608361601829529 ], [ 441323.869715572451241, 5538263.648547666147351 ], [ 441384.69124153238954, 5538295.938052516430616 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "fid": 4.0, "o2 (in %)": 92.0, "no3 (mg\/l)": 6.0, "ph-wert": 6.0, "nh4 (mg\/l)": 0.04, "no2 (mg\/l)": 0.3, "scale": 7000 }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ 440941.620893525949214, 5537051.748555677011609 ], [ 440984.535816266899928, 5537123.829144899733365 ], [ 441022.524805039749481, 5537218.361542447470129 ], [ 441095.221280025958549, 5537367.778988471254706 ], [ 441103.430673010763712, 5537468.303140427917242 ], [ 441166.269104428705759, 5537626.325040364637971 ], [ 441168.047478649707045, 5537658.897531099617481 ], [ 441259.126606045640074, 5537801.01802884042263 ], [ 441361.876772109535523, 5537971.347719811834395 ], [ 441388.317306230019312, 5538050.407540929503739 ], [ 441344.125541774032172, 5538167.078247386962175 ], [ 441362.05696347419871, 5538247.645037651993334 ], [ 441384.502329971117433, 5538295.968604033812881 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "fid": 5.0, "o2 (in %)": 60.0, "no3 (mg\/l)": 4.0, "ph-wert": 5.3, "nh4 (mg\/l)": 0.05, "no2 (mg\/l)": 0.18, "scale": 13000 }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ 444503.570831720135175, 5538997.400540792383254 ], [ 444542.392090781475417, 5539004.18024480342865 ], [ 444648.868999591795728, 5539031.943952777422965 ], [ 444710.399683696625289, 5539057.871022731997073 ], [ 444723.194584990793373, 5539058.801531734876335 ], [ 444726.610123310238123, 5539062.839158355258405 ], [ 444733.37728233623784, 5539064.717258594930172 ], [ 444734.815976074372884, 5539066.473226956091821 ], [ 444740.900292722857557, 5539071.014579127542675 ], [ 444748.11380950344028, 5539081.742089434526861 ], [ 444771.380679900408722, 5539082.210604277439415 ], [ 444776.386853803298436, 5539085.523534629493952 ], [ 444778.228067258722149, 5539091.879427048377693 ], [ 444786.993860318616498, 5539098.163973402231932 ], [ 444799.330756850773469, 5539106.359613505192101 ], [ 444807.355292531428859, 5539109.641470400616527 ], [ 444813.589703730889596, 5539111.525139356032014 ], [ 444820.883959253085777, 5539112.866667102091014 ], [ 444824.996841031766962, 5539115.657583434134722 ], [ 444833.055973989074118, 5539122.303606402128935 ], [ 444837.359151145617943, 5539126.33211606554687 ], [ 444843.414157298393548, 5539128.040581359528005 ], [ 444849.996350771340076, 5539129.212393677793443 ], [ 444852.137910659075715, 5539130.252826166339219 ], [ 444854.297687702986877, 5539133.063852198421955 ], [ 444855.225527949922252, 5539136.950020257383585 ], [ 444858.446969612326939, 5539139.395965347997844 ], [ 444860.94909254158847, 5539140.963922853581607 ], [ 444864.170529152033851, 5539143.409869476221502 ], [ 444871.673240330070257, 5539147.759630839340389 ], [ 444874.186282303300686, 5539150.389944178052247 ], [ 444879.748655303323176, 5539155.999209297820926 ], [ 444887.76760375907179, 5539158.749978988431394 ], [ 444889.200759540544823, 5539159.974781745113432 ], [ 444895.478772819507867, 5539166.107924435287714 ], [ 444897.096757557010278, 5539168.039134507998824 ], [ 444899.618879073066637, 5539171.554739489220083 ], [ 444911.228849762817845, 5539178.16430152207613 ], [ 444931.472192217770498, 5539195.486804950982332 ], [ 444950.448913972824812, 5539210.520356138236821 ], [ 444957.373351147281937, 5539210.449236093088984 ], [ 444960.799525652022567, 5539215.549232815392315 ], [ 444967.925140598788857, 5539217.778037323616445 ], [ 444975.962127650040202, 5539222.299468290992081 ], [ 444979.212545475165825, 5539227.578344127163291 ], [ 444982.230880156974308, 5539227.547358111478388 ], [ 444984.955911910394207, 5539233.539923885837197 ], [ 444995.485811869322788, 5539238.744077912531793 ], [ 445026.559521985589527, 5539273.308793476782739 ], [ 445028.699173216416966, 5539274.17221250385046 ], [ 445034.39703756920062, 5539275.707430430687964 ], [ 445036.330085953464732, 5539273.73980023432523 ], [ 445040.404601315327454, 5539272.812648594379425 ], [ 445045.020838544587605, 5539272.765311332419515 ], [ 445048.416027733183, 5539274.855376338586211 ], [ 445050.048447368084453, 5539278.203027833253145 ], [ 445051.86930413817754, 5539282.611183260567486 ], [ 445052.074080936610699, 5539285.265176765620708 ], [ 445051.200867740961257, 5539286.690712151117623 ], [ 445050.148292570607737, 5539287.941013601608574 ], [ 445048.570338448567782, 5539289.904992670752108 ], [ 445048.077637007518206, 5539293.805642087943852 ], [ 445048.103053118975367, 5539296.284396600909531 ], [ 445048.126653791056015, 5539298.586096200160682 ], [ 445048.170224254776258, 5539302.83538518473506 ], [ 445048.692336371925194, 5539319.120654282160103 ], [ 445051.033111243741587, 5539322.283943491056561 ], [ 445053.3738833675161, 5539325.447231817059219 ], [ 445055.355930867663119, 5539328.260054174810648 ], [ 445059.100727247016039, 5539329.81530502345413 ], [ 445063.724174973671325, 5539330.476194459944963 ], [ 445067.836762073682621, 5539333.267179316841066 ], [ 445074.971247185778338, 5539336.381336653605103 ], [ 445075.154236314469017, 5539336.910674606449902 ], [ 445074.685109896527138, 5539343.11296780128032 ], [ 445074.712328436900862, 5539345.768751772120595 ], [ 445077.256024260772392, 5539351.408945753239095 ], [ 445077.993421096354723, 5539354.057447520084679 ], [ 445081.747264435980469, 5539356.497965719550848 ], [ 445081.750893114833161, 5539356.852069442160428 ], [ 445086.046685122419149, 5539377.525252304971218 ], [ 445089.122986195026897, 5539383.159960478544235 ], [ 445091.304306094883941, 5539388.095556491985917 ], [ 445097.032866158231627, 5539392.640668426640332 ], [ 445103.147335298999678, 5539400.192003171890974 ], [ 445105.373974823800381, 5539409.553843722678721 ], [ 445108.629593910241965, 5539415.363760245963931 ], [ 445111.33625766239129, 5539419.585679761134088 ], [ 445112.43052736565005, 5539422.407565166242421 ], [ 445116.43075186398346, 5539431.574138262309134 ], [ 445118.45624311681604, 5539438.636108800768852 ], [ 445120.467224532156251, 5539444.281679153442383 ], [ 445123.538013047655113, 5539449.385189610533416 ], [ 445130.502020521438681, 5539453.209363294765353 ], [ 445137.618184168764856, 5539454.553045297972858 ], [ 445138.335600308026187, 5539455.253969573415816 ], [ 445149.457338592968881, 5539466.295344308950007 ], [ 445150.819768608198501, 5539495.320275097154081 ], [ 445162.504817527660634, 5539509.365938354283571 ], [ 445172.015838817460462, 5539536.53661748021841 ], [ 445200.999586171063129, 5539592.723418585956097 ], [ 445231.522646420635283, 5539643.228095235303044 ], [ 445242.813376576290466, 5539705.614845015108585 ], [ 445248.275041925662663, 5539718.838434093631804 ], [ 445268.984569646767341, 5539729.958597558550537 ], [ 445284.906069280114025, 5539741.65887629520148 ], [ 445287.1105668215896, 5539748.895724552683532 ], [ 445299.031883047602605, 5539768.781462080776691 ], [ 445293.948548850603402, 5539775.207394906319678 ], [ 445291.089586363639683, 5539790.817534318193793 ], [ 445291.199845499999356, 5539801.616813910193741 ], [ 445316.661098420619965, 5539860.847282757051289 ], [ 445322.399803986481857, 5539866.454435206949711 ], [ 445325.370311582111754, 5539879.171960248611867 ], [ 445331.110794812964741, 5539884.956136908382177 ], [ 445334.016251381894108, 5539891.300393846817315 ], [ 445336.762234806781635, 5539899.416795822791755 ], [ 445337.894217662455048, 5539905.956182369031012 ], [ 445336.399424291099422, 5539916.06339643150568 ], [ 445335.58042467024643, 5539922.799717777408659 ], [ 445335.266913022496738, 5539926.875102101825178 ], [ 445336.022168320720084, 5539931.293682500720024 ], [ 445336.047453389503062, 5539933.772142833098769 ], [ 445336.092605289362837, 5539938.197962020523846 ], [ 445334.151944904879201, 5539956.808096547611058 ], [ 445331.012491279689129, 5539962.328690385445952 ], [ 445328.577723154972773, 5539967.310939843766391 ], [ 445328.108371826121584, 5539973.51248128246516 ], [ 445328.169787649880163, 5539979.531550157815218 ], [ 445330.723763154936023, 5539986.23337815515697 ], [ 445332.390114112233277, 5539992.944255043752491 ], [ 445333.886162254028022, 5540000.365057868883014 ], [ 445329.531167244713288, 5540008.553743331693113 ], [ 445327.270332442945801, 5540013.180079243145883 ], [ 445326.291902678553015, 5540021.688392317853868 ], [ 445324.056367323268205, 5540028.793135127983987 ], [ 445323.251855076989159, 5540036.945553827099502 ], [ 445321.025363444117829, 5540044.93542399909347 ], [ 445317.437864738982171, 5540076.132328742183745 ], [ 445311.022741607623175, 5540108.597236700356007 ], [ 445306.809249913669191, 5540113.243428451009095 ], [ 445300.015305858221836, 5540160.76074368879199 ], [ 445268.57171350804856, 5540228.35810287296772 ], [ 445282.284620796737727, 5540284.694024560041726 ], [ 445281.613342906406615, 5540340.645162952132523 ], [ 445295.403198275016621, 5540421.941177251748741 ], [ 445332.558520154270809, 5540496.624330694787204 ], [ 445341.453186541679315, 5540507.38438611663878 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "fid": 6.0, "o2 (in %)": 45.0, "no3 (mg\/l)": 6.0, "ph-wert": 5.5, "nh4 (mg\/l)": 0.05, "no2 (mg\/l)": 0.2, "scale": 10000 }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ 445341.453186541679315, 5540507.38438611663878 ], [ 445419.193566703237593, 5540601.428475308232009 ], [ 445441.088759432721417, 5540624.750277404673398 ], [ 445474.881795341905672, 5540648.482032387517393 ], [ 445501.932314654462971, 5540655.110845257528126 ], [ 445532.249106257804669, 5540651.261959870345891 ], [ 445576.706219767220318, 5540623.901874651201069 ], [ 445607.16625931893941, 5540529.235568709671497 ], [ 445668.762797841627616, 5540546.313630769960582 ], [ 445803.587556450860575, 5540572.21062892396003 ], [ 445775.107296372181736, 5540669.864389293827116 ], [ 445787.768830923363566, 5540693.103710719384253 ], [ 445911.095938147744164, 5540741.070010594092309 ], [ 446142.088206757907756, 5540833.62669412791729 ], [ 446241.496983615506906, 5540904.498137251473963 ], [ 446380.038474728935398, 5541054.635208867490292 ], [ 446479.442260472569615, 5541161.264134122058749 ], [ 446471.1199163175188, 5541216.574111967347562 ], [ 446475.339375200448558, 5541248.039293149486184 ] ] } }
]
}
```

Any ideas on what the problem is?

Comment: Your GeoJSON is not strictly a GeoJSON: it does not use WGS 84 coordinates (longitude, latitude) but another projection. The coordinates you use are outside the extent of WGS 84 (longitude between -180 and 180 and latitude between -90 and 90). You need to find out the projection of the data.

Comment: Please edit your question and add relevant code where you create your GeoJSON layer. Wrong projection should not cause the above error, just layer not being showed (correctly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get it to work, though the LineStrings are really hard to spot because you are not using a large amount of coordinates. Your coordinates are a small line near the borders of France with Italy and the projection you are using for your GeoJSON is EPSG:3857 as much as I can tell. Instead of reading the geometry with GeoJSON().readGeometry(), try reading the features with GeoJSON().readFeatures() and pass an object with your source and destination projections as its' second parameter. The below example worked on my end on a map with EPSG:3857 projection. readGeometry() will try to find a geometry property inside your geojson while readFeatures() is more suitable for FeatureCollections because it searches immediatelly in the features property. Hope the below snippet helps.

```
    let layer = new VectorLayer({
      source: new VectorSource({
         features: new GeoJSON().readFeatures(geojson, {dataProjection: 'EPSG: 3857', featureProjection: 'EPSG: 3857'})
       })
    });

    layer.getSource().getFeatures().map(feat => {
        feat.setStyle(new Style({
             fill: new Fill({
                 color: 'rgba(0,0,255,1)'
             }),
             stroke: new Stroke({
                 color: 'rgba(0,0,255,1)',
                 width: 15
              })
         }));
     });
     map.addLayer(layer);
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I still don't get the layer on my website. I think I did it pretty much as you suggested just in a different order. 

I just created a fresh question with a new error message and my whole code to better organize my question though.